# How to read integers from a char string, when you dont know how many integers there is? (in C)

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char nameOfFile[] = "blablabla.txt";
char lineG [128];

static char * readLine()
{
    static FILE *file;
    if(file == NULL)
        file = fopen ( nameOfFile, "r" ); //opens the file

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        if( fgets ( lineG, sizeof (lineG), file ) != NULL ) //reads a line from file
            return lineG;
        else
            fclose ( file );
    }

    else perror ( nameOfFile ); 
    return NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
    char *line, a;
    line=readLine();
    char c;
    int a[30],b[30];

    sscanf(line,"%c %d%d%d%d",&c,a[0],b[0],a[1],b[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

As you see there i am trying to read int strings from a file. but i dont know how many int couples (like 12,23;) there will be. i am looking for a solution fits all.
txt file will be like this(two or more lines)

```
A 12,54;34,65;54,56;98,90   
B 23,87;56,98
```

Comment: That check for `NULL` on `file` *before initializing it* is wrong.

Comment: @unwind Note that the variable is declared `static`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Gaah, thanks! Totally missed that. Then the check is just pointless, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%n` format specifier and read one integer at a time. The associated argument for 
`%n` is populated with the index of the string where `sscanf()` read to. Description for format specifier `n` from the C99 standard:

> No input is consumed. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from
>   the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function**. Execution of a
>   %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the
>   completion of execution of the fscanf function. No argument is converted,
>   but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes an assignment suppressing
>   character or a field width, the behavior is undefined.

A dynamically allocated array (using `malloc()`) would be required to store the `int`s and be extended (using `realloc()`) as required. Simple example for reading the `int`s (but not adding to an array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char* in = "15 16 17 18";
    int i;
    int pos = 0;
    int total_pos = 0;

    while (1 == sscanf(in + total_pos, "%d%n", &i, &pos))
    {
        total_pos += pos;
        printf("i=%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See online demo @ http://ideone.com/sWcgw0 .

Answer (score 1):

To read X numbers, you simply read one at a time in a loop. The problem here though, is that the numbers are not separated by space but by commas and semicolons. This can not be easily be handled by a simple `sscanf`.

Instead I suggest you first extract the letter first in the line, and then use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the remaining on the semicolon, and then use `strtok` again to split on comma. Then you can use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the numbers in the string into integer values.